# Confluent Kafka GCS(Google Cloud Storage) Connector giving a parse error on loading the properties file

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-storage, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm new to Confluent and I am trying to use GCS as the sink after exporting data from Kafka. I am following this guide: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-gcs/index.html

I get the following error when I tried to [start the connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-gcs/index.html#start-the-connector)

```
This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

parse error: Expected separator between values at line 1, column 644
{
  "error_code": 500,
  "message": null
}
```

I've searched for a solution but can't seem to find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the property file you're loading. See [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 It is exactly like the one in the link I have mentioned. Just that I have given the absolute path for _gcs.credentials.path_. Anyway I solved the issue if someone runs into it in the future. Just remove the double quotes _""_ assigned to _confluent.license_ .

Comment: Well, you'll need a license key if you want that connector to continue running

Comment: @cricket_007 AFAIK you can run the connector without a licence, it'll just require one after the 30 day trial.

Comment: @Robin Right. Hence I said "continue running"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if someone runs into it in the future. Just remove the double quotes "" assigned to confluent.license